# How to create this type of brush in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

Can a brush be created in Photoshop to make it look like the white board marker brush strokes in the below picture? I tried several brushes but none seems to achieve the below kind of an effect.

Help, please?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you *can* create a brush which would mimic the way dry erase markers sort of blend and delete portions of previous marks. 90% of the "dry erase effect" is due to the whiteboard being drawn on and how the ink from the marker reacts to *that* specific surface. On paper, a dry erase marker is just like any other marker. If it's at all possible to mimic the whiteboard effect, it would take considerable experimentation with the brush settings. Offhand, a dual brush with color dynamics perhaps?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Scott. I wanted to ask you another question - is there a blending mode called Compare Density in Photoshop for brushes?